# Implicit conversion from data type datetime to numeric is not allowed

Tags: sql-server, datetime, triggers, insert

Getting the following error: Line 21 is the declare statement.
I can't figure this out. Done_ON is clearly of type datetime, why is the compiler complaining?
Thanks.

Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Procedure insert_employee_details, Line 21
Implicit conversion from data type datetime to numeric is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

```
Use [StacysDB];
Go


--CREATE TABLE DB_Actions
--(
--Id numeric(5,0) IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
--Table_Name varchar(20),
--Action_Name varchar(10),
--User_Name varchar(50),
--Done_ON datetime,
--Record_Id numeric(5,0)
--);


--INSERT TRIGGER
CREATE TRIGGER insert_employee_details
ON Employee_Details
FOR INSERT
AS
DECLARE @id int, @name varchar(20)
SELECT @id = Emp_Id, @name = Emp_First_Name FROM inserted
INSERT INTO DB_Actions
VALUES(@id,
        'Employee_Details',
        'INSERT',
        @name,
        getdate()
)
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should *always* list the columns for `insert`:

```
INSERT INTO DB_Actions(id, table_name, action_name, user_name, done_on)
    VALUES(@id,
            'Employee_Details',
            'INSERT',
            @name,
            getdate()
    );
```

You are missing the `Record_Id`.  I'm not sure why it would generate this error, though.  You would get this error if `Record_Id` is really the 5th column in the table.

A more proper way to write the trigger is to assume that `inserted` could have multiple rows:

```
INSERT INTO DB_Actions(id, table_name, action_name, user_name, done_on)
    SELECT Emp_Id, 'Employee_Details', 'INSERT', Emp_First_Name, getdate()
    FROM inserted;
```

This, at least, will not generate an error sometime when you insert multiple rows at the same time.

Comment: apparently the problem was I didnt list the 5th column. thanks. answer accepted

Answer (score 0):

Id column in table DB_Actions is identity column, not allowed for INSERT statement in the trigger, so you miss fifth column, thus SQL Server tried to convert GetDate() into Record_Id, hence caused the error.